# ReactJS - console.log(ObjectName) //Working console.log(ObjectName.property) //Property not recognized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I will need help with the following code please

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import APIService from './service/ApiService'

export default function App() {

    useEffect(() => {
        APIService.getAdminApp('KYC').then(donnees => { //stats
            updateStats(donnees)
        }).catch(function (ex) {
            console.log('Erreur de parsing')
        });
    },[]);

    const [stats, updateStats] = useState([]);
    const keys = stats.application
    
    console.log(keys)
    
    
    return(<div>
    </div>);
}
```

The moment i do `console.log(keys)`, the content of the object is displayed correctly.

[image]

But when I do `console.log(keys.name)`, the property name is not recognized.

[image: log don't working]

Why?
For information, my getAdminApp function in the useEffect uses a GET on an API fetch.
Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(stats.application)`?

Comment: Seems to me that you need to guard against the initial (empty) value of `stats`. So you can do `if (stats.application) { ... }`, or possibly optional chaining `stats?.application?.name`

Comment: @YasinBr  I added images

Comment: @MattU Sorry but its don't working :'(

Comment: @MattU Finally it's working!! ^^ I do:
<p>{keys?.name}</p> Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did:

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import APIService from './service/ApiService'

export default function App() {

    useEffect(() => {
        APIService.getAdminApp('KYC').then(donnees => { //stats
            updateStats(donnees)
        }).catch(function (ex) {
            console.log('Erreur de parsing')
        });
    },[]);

    const [stats, updateStats] = useState([]);
    const keys = stats.application
    const array = stats.statistiqueList
    return(<div>
        <p>{keys?.name}</p>
        <p>{array[0]?.code}</p>
    </div>);
}
```

It's working, thanks you! ^^